Failed polling endpoint: imaps: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected
For my Springboot+Apache Camel+Camel-Mail app I keep getting the below error. I already double confirmed the OAuth2 creds for my mailbox and all is Ok there. Only the IMAP fails but the mails are successfully sent over SMTP. Any one faced a similar issue? I am using Camel 3.20.6.
A3 LIST "" INBOX
A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
[30m2024-09-16 20:49:16,795[0;39m [31mWARN [0;39m [[34mCamel (camel) thread
 #1 - imaps://my-outlook.office365.com:my-port[0;39m]
                [33morg.apache.camel.spi.CamelLogger[0;39m: Failed polling endpoint: imaps
://my-outlook.office365.com:my-port?authenticator=%23exchangeAuthenticator&debugMode=tr
ue&delay=10000&delete=false&mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms=XOAUTH2&mail.imaps.proxy.
host=10.XXX.YYY.6&mail.imaps.proxy.port=8**0&searchTerm=%23customSearch&unse
en=true. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [javax.mail.MessagingException 
- A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.]
javax.mail.MessagingException: A3 BAD User is authenticated but not connected.
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.doCommand(IMAPFolder.java:3844)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.exists(IMAPFolder.java:566)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.ensureIsConnected(MailConsumer.
java:611)
    at org.apache.camel.component.mail.MailConsumer.poll(MailConsumer.java:128)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.j
ava:202)



It seems like a permission rights issue related to IMAP protocol. Can you check you are authorized to access IMAP folder ?

@драган-јованковић, thank you. I did that already but the permissions (clientID/clientSecret) are all fine. I suspect am I polling the mailbox too often through my camel process?
